# Graphics warning before and after making connection to SystemModelSimulation

Tags: graphics, system-modeling, warning, wsmrealtimesimulate

System modeling in MMA took a giant step forward with the integration of Modelica capabilities into Wolfram Language. Uptake seems slow, but it's worth the effort (despite the challenges.)

One problem can be seen in the bouncing ball example below where evaluation of `Graphics[..]` results in the pink warning background before starting the realtime simulation, and after it stops. To see the problem first evaluate the code below:

```
eqs = {v[t] == h'[t], v'[t] == -9.81, WhenEvent[h[t] <= 0, v[t] -> -k v[t]], h[0] == 1};
model = CreateSystemModel[eqs, t];
diskColor[h_] := Which[h >= 100, Red, h < 100, Blue];
g1 = Graphics[Dynamic[Refresh[{diskColor[conn["h"]], Disk[]}, UpdateInterval -> 0.1]]]
```

Unsurprisingly, Mathematica gives a warning `'Which is not a graphics primitive or directive'`. Now instance the realtime simulation connection `conn` and press the run button.

```
Needs["WSMLink`"];
conn = WSMRealTimeSimulate[model, 10]
```

At this point the Graphic[] warning disappears.

This behavior stems from the function `diskColor[conn["h"]]` which is `None` until we run the simulation at which point `conn["h"]` dynamically connects to the simulation, the pink disappears, only to return when the connection ends.

My question is whether we can avoid the pink warning which in this case serves no purpose. If I should duplicate over at Wolfram Community let me know.

Comment: "conn" is not defined

Comment: Sorry Daniel just edited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restrict the definition of `diskColor` only to numeric `h`, and define a default value for non-numeric `h` (ie. when `conn` is not established yet).

```
Clear[diskColor];
diskColor[h_?NumericQ] := Which[h >= 100, Red, h < 100, Blue];
diskColor[_] := Black;
```